# Assign Multiple Tasks from one Task by tweaking Approval Workflow

Tags: workflow

What Approval Workflow does is creates multiple approvals from a single task whereby the assignee has to approval or reject the task.

Now, Is there a way assign Multiple Tasks from one Task by tweaking Approval Workflow?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this via a Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer Custom Workflow... that said, could you give a possible scenario so that i could give a more specific suggestion?

Comment: I want that a Project Team Leader, from one task, can assign it to multiple users. Is this possible with Approval workflow or something else?